# Unable to update the record because of validation of name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
namespace :send_query do    
    task :to_admins => :environment do 
        contacts = Contact.select(:name, :mobile, :company, :requirement).where(email_sent: false).distinct
        if !contacts.blank?
            contacts.each do |contact|
                GuestMailer.query_email(contact.name,
          contact.mobile,
          contact.company,
          contact.requirement).deliver
          contact.update!(email_sent: true)
            end 
        end
        puts "done sending query emails"
    end
end
```

I wrote a rake task to send emails. After sending email, I am updating the field email_sent to true. But the transaction is rolling back after sending email.

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Contact Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."name" = $1 AND ("contacts"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "contacts"."mobile" = $2 AND "contacts"."requirement" = $3 AND "contacts"."company" = $4 LIMIT $5  [["name", "vamsi pavan mahesh"], ["mobile", "9247474925"], ["requirement", "yo yo honey singhu"], ["company", "mahesh@bla.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name has already been taken
```

Here is the Contact model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: contacts
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name        :string
#  mobile      :string
#  company     :string
#  requirement :text
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#  email_sent  :boolean          default(FALSE)
#

class Contact < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true 
    validates :mobile, presence: true
    validates :requirement, presence: true
    validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: [:mobile, :requirement, :company]
end
```

Comment: to bypass validation you can do `contact.update_attribute(:email_sent, true)`

Comment: i want validation! can you please re read the question

Comment: This is something I don't like with validations: once you saved your record, and after some time you add another validation and this old record cannot pass this validation, you can't update it anymore, even if you don't change the attribute that makes the validation fails. A workaround to his is to use the `if` condition of the validates: `validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: [:mobile, :requirement, :company] }, if: 'self.name_changed?'`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko bypassing the validation should only be done in very rare conditions. Especially not in a rake task that is meant to run from time to time

Comment: @MrYoshiji agree, I don't think bypassing validation is acceptable at all (or, as you say, super rarely). Otherwise why have it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `Contact` model, you can do `on: :create` and that will only apply that validate on the create action.

<strike>`validates :name, presence: true, on: :create`</strike>

EDIT:

As MrYoshiji pointed out in the comments, it's the `uniqueness` validation on the name that is causing the validation error, so the fix would actually be:

`validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: [:mobile, :requirement, :company] }, on: :create`

Comment: I think you meant `validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: [:mobile, :requirement, :company] }, on: :create` since the failing validation is about the name uniqueness, not the name presence.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's correct. I'll update my answer to what MrYoshiji said.

Comment: I think this is not robust. If we scope things to on: :create. An already created record can be updated to have a duplicate name when its updated